# Android - AsyncTask never ends

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask, jsch

I have written a network (JSch) async task for Android. For some reason, the AsyncTask never ends until I call buttonClick() again. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

{
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

```
    protected void buttonClick(View view)
    {
            System.out.println(" --------------------------------- ");
            System.out.println(" CONNECT BUTTON CLICKED!");
            System.out.println(" --------------------------------- ");
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
                    {
                            connect();
                            System.out.println("Connect done");
                            return null;
                    }
                    protected Void onPostExecute()
                    {
                            System.out.println("PostExec done");
                            return null;
                    }
            }.execute();
            System.out.println("Done with ASyncTask");
            String text = output;
            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ayy);
            tv.setText(text);
    }

    private int d;
    private String output;
    private void debug()
    {
            System.out.println("Debug" + d);
            d++;
    }

    private void connect()
    {
            d = 1;
            debug();
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            String host = "[edited out]";
            String user = "[edited out]";
            String password = "[edited out for obvious reasons]";
            String command = "uname -a";
            int port = 2223;
            try {
                    debug();
                    Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
                    debug();
                    UserInfo ui = new MyUserInfo();
                    debug();
                    session.setUserInfo(ui);
                    debug();
                    session.connect();
                    debug();
                    Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
                    debug();
                    ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
                    debug();
                    channel.setInputStream(null);
                    debug();
                    ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);
                    debug();
                    InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
                    debug();
                    channel.connect();
                    debug();
                    byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
                    while(true) {
                            while(in.available() > 0) {
                                    int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                                    if(i < 0) break;
                                    output = output + new String(tmp, 0, i);
                            }
                            if(channel.isClosed()) {
                                    if(in.available() > 0) continue;
                                    System.out.println("exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus());
                                    break;
                            }
                            try {
                                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                            } catch(Exception ee) {

                            }
                    }
                    channel.disconnect();
                    session.disconnect();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                    System.err.println("Exception: " + e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
  }

  class MyUserInfo implements UserInfo, UIKeyboardInteractive
  {
    public String getPassword()
    {
            return passwd;
    }

    public boolean promptYesNo(String str)
    {
                    /*Object[] options = {"yes", "no"};
                    int foo = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                            str,
                            "Warning",
                            JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,
                            JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
                            null, options, options[0]);
                    return foo == 0; */
            return true;
    }

    String passwd;

    public String getPassphrase()
    {
            return null;
    }

    public boolean promptPassphrase(String message)
    {
            return true;
    }

    public boolean promptPassword(String message)
    {
            passwd = "[edited out]";
            return true;
    }

    public void showMessage(String message)
    {
            System.out.println("MSG: " + message);
    }

    /*
    final GridBagConstraints gbc =
            new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                    GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST,
                    GridBagConstraints.NONE,
                    new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0);
    private Container panel;
    */
    public String[] promptKeyboardInteractive(String destination,
                                              String name,
                                              String instruction,
                                              String[] prompt,
                                              boolean[] echo)
    { System.out.println("promptKeyboardInteractive");/*
            panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            gbc.weightx = 1.0;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            panel.add(new JLabel(instruction), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;

            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;

            JTextField[] texts = new JTextField[prompt.length];
            for(int i = 0; i < prompt.length; i++) {
                    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
                    gbc.gridx = 0;
                    gbc.weightx = 1;
                    panel.add(new JLabel(prompt[i]), gbc);

                    gbc.gridx = 1;
                    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                    gbc.weighty = 1;
                    if(echo[i]) {
                            texts[i] = new JTextField(20);
                    } else {
                            texts[i] = new JPasswordField(20);
                    }
                    panel.add(texts[i], gbc);
                    gbc.gridy++;
            }

            if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel,
                    destination + ": " + name,
                    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE)
                    == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                    String[] response = new String[prompt.length];
                    for(int i = 0; i < prompt.length; i++) {
                            response[i] = texts[i].getText();
                    }
                    return response;
            } else {
                    return null;  // cancel
            }
    */
            return null;
      }
}
```

I'm fully aware that the code is a complete mess but I'll clean it up once I get this working.

Output after 1 button click:

```
04-13 15:45:33.451 26826-26826/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out:  --------------------------------- 
04-13 15:45:33.451 26826-26826/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out:  CONNECT BUTTON CLICKED!
04-13 15:45:33.451 26826-26826/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out:  --------------------------------- 
04-13 15:45:33.452 26826-26826/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Done with Asynctask
04-13 15:45:33.452 26826-26925/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Debug1
04-13 15:45:33.457 26826-26925/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Debug2
04-13 15:45:33.470 26826-26925/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Debug3
04-13 15:45:33.470 26826-26925/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Debug4
04-13 15:45:33.470 26826-26925/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Debug5
04-13 15:45:33.472 26826-26925/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Connecting: 192.168.1.18:2223
04-13 15:45:34.008 26826-26925/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Debug6
 04-13 15:45:34.013 26826-26925/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Debug7
 04-13 15:45:34.013 26826-26925/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Debug8
 04-13 15:45:34.013 26826-26925/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Debug9
  04-13 15:45:34.013 26826-26925/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Debug10
  04-13 15:45:34.014 26826-26925/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Debug11
 04-13 15:45:34.076 26826-26925/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Debug12
 04-13 15:45:35.112 26826-26925/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: exit-status: 0
 04-13 15:45:35.115 26826-26925/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out:     Connect done
```

Output after 2 button clicks:

```
04-13 15:45:33.451 26826-26826/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out:  --------------------------------- 
04-13 15:45:33.451 26826-26826/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out:  CONNECT BUTTON CLICKED!
04-13 15:45:33.451 26826-26826/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out:  --------------------------------- 
04-13 15:45:33.452 26826-26826/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Done with Asynctask
04-13 15:45:33.452 26826-26925/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Debug1
04-13 15:45:33.457 26826-26925/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Debug2
04-13 15:45:33.470 26826-26925/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Debug3
04-13 15:45:33.470 26826-26925/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Debug4
04-13 15:45:33.470 26826-26925/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Debug5
04-13 15:45:34.008 26826-26925/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Debug6
04-13 15:45:34.013 26826-26925/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Debug7
04-13 15:45:34.013 26826-26925/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Debug8
04-13 15:45:34.013 26826-26925/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Debug9
04-13 15:45:34.013 26826-26925/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Debug10
04-13 15:45:34.014 26826-26925/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Debug11
04-13 15:45:34.076 26826-26925/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Debug12
04-13 15:45:35.112 26826-26925/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: exit-status: 0
04-13 15:45:35.115 26826-26925/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Connect done
04-13 15:47:32.784 26826-26826/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out:  --------------------------------- 
04-13 15:47:32.784 26826-26826/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out:  CONNECT BUTTON CLICKED!
04-13 15:47:32.784 26826-26826/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out:  --------------------------------- 
04-13 15:47:32.785 26826-26826/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Done with Asynctask
04-13 15:47:32.785 26826-28694/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Debug1
04-13 15:47:32.786 26826-28694/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Debug2
04-13 15:47:32.786 26826-28694/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Debug3
04-13 15:47:32.786 26826-28694/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Debug4
04-13 15:47:32.786 26826-28694/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Debug5
04-13 15:47:33.370 26826-28694/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Debug6
04-13 15:47:33.370 26826-28694/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Debug7
04-13 15:47:33.370 26826-28694/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Debug8
04-13 15:47:33.370 26826-28694/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Debug9
04-13 15:47:33.370 26826-28694/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Debug10
04-13 15:47:33.371 26826-28694/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Debug11
04-13 15:47:33.436 26826-28694/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Debug12
04-13 15:47:34.467 26826-28694/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: exit-status: 0
04-13 15:47:34.468 26826-28694/com.example.ryan.jschtest I/System.out: Connect done
```

Comment: Your code is unreadable

Comment: @IvanMilisavljevic This code is pretty bad but surely it's not that bad?

Answer (score -1):

Solved:

```
public boolean connectComplete = false;

protected void buttonClick(View view)
{
    ConnectTask ayy = new ConnectTask();
    ayy.execute();
    while(!connectComplete) {
        try { Thread.sleep(100); } catch(Exception e) {System.out.println(e); e.printStackTrace; } 
    }
    ayy.cancel(true);
    connectComplete = false;
}
```

in ConnectTask:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
{
        MainActivity.connect();
        cancel(true);
        System.out.println("Connect done");
        connectComplete = true;
        return null;
}
```

Comment: This looks like a bad solution. You are sleeping on the main thread which blocks the entire UI of the app and are waiting on the async task to finish which defeats the entire purpose of it running asynchronous.

Comment: @RobCo The task never takes more than a half second, and runs at app startup. It uses network so I am forced to run is asynchronous. Is there a better solution to use?

Comment: Better would be to pass a Callback to the Task it can invoke when it is done, or just have it call a separate method in your MainActivity. This should be done in `onPostExecute` so that it is called on the main thread again. This way the main thread can do other things while `doInBackground` is executing

Comment: @RobCo Thanks will try this now